# Mapbox Filtering Multipe Tile Layers at Once

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Is it possible to set a filter for multiple tile layers at once? I currently have data stored in vector tile and the filters I am applying are near instantaneous - which is awesome!

That said, I would like to filter two different geometry types (line and circle) at once on the map. Each line will be tied to a circle.

Is this possible to do easily? It would be great if anyone knows of an example.

Thanks!!

Comment: You can just iterate through all your layers and apply the same filter to each..

Answer (score 1):

Using mapbox-gl-js, it's as simple as:

```js
for (const each layer of ['layer1', 'layer2']) {
    map.setFilter(layer, myNewFilter)
}
```

Or with [mapbox-gl-utils](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mapbox-gl-utils):

```js
   map.U.setFilter(['layer1', 'layer2'], myNewFilter);
```